# Why does my td height doesn't seem to adjust?

Tags: html, css, html-table, height

I've been creating a table for an email template. I wanted to decrease the height of my TDs but can't

note: the two TDs with rgb(41,62,151) bg color, 5% width, colspan of 2, 100px height which I can't decrease.

```html
 

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 10pt; border-collapse: collapse">
<tbody style="margin: 0">

<tr>
<td colspan="14" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); border-bottom-color: rgb(41, 62, 151)">
<img src="an image here">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); height: 100px; width: 5%">
<br>
</td>

<td colspan="10" style="background-color: white; height: 350px; width: 90%; 
padding: 30px 100px">
<p style="text-align: justify"><span style="color: rgb(42, 61, 151); font-
family: Callibri, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: large; text-align: left">some text here</span><b style="color: rgb(42, 61, 151); font-family: 
Callibri, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: large; text-align: left">&nbsp;</b>
</p><p style="text-align: justify">
<font color="#283e97">text here</font><br>some text here<br><br><span 
style="color: rgb(40, 62, 151)">some text here<br><br><span style="color: 
rgb(40, 62, 151)">

some text here</span><br>Some text here</p>
</td>

<td colspan="2" style="background-color: rgb(41, 62, 151); height: 100px; width: 5%">
<br>
</td>

</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help appreciated! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients have limited CSS support, so the style attribute may not have any effect.  Try using td's height attribute.

```
<td height="100px">...</td>
```

Comment: hmm I have tried the height attribute in both of the tds that I want to adjust but it still doesn't seem to work.